# My html images don't work although the code is right

Tags: html, css, image

Almost every single time that I add an image in my code in VS code, it is broken in the browser.
I always make sure to have the image in the exact same folder as the rest of code, or in an images folder which I have in the same folder as the rest of my code, but it still does not work.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```html
<img src="/ae24874dd301843548c034a3d2973658.png" alt="" class="cat">
```

And the .png is in the same folder as the rest of my code files. Why does it still not show?

Edit: Ok so I "made it work" by opening it through the live server extension (by pressing Go Live, after first restarting the program). But if I try to open it through chrome the images are still broken. It is still weird to me...

Comment: Try using your browsers deveoper console and look for an error message to help you diagnose the problem. Also the forward slash looks weird, I've never done that if the file exists in the same directory, I have used ./ though.

Comment: if you use site-absolute URL's you need a web server to see the page

Comment: Are you on your local machine with no serving? If so don't give it a URL, remove the /.

Comment: @L777 No? How? Sorry i just started learning html and css 5 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

As the image is in same folder, use this

```
<img src="./image.png" alt="" class="cat">
```

Answer (score 1):

With `/` you start at the root of the Computer or Server. Try using a relative path.

On Windows `/` is `C:\` drive. If you use a localhost like xampp the htdocs folder is the root.
Without the `/` your path will start at the same folder as your html

Try

```html
<img src="ae24874dd301843548c034a3d2973658.png" alt="" class="cat">
```

or

```html
<img src="./ae24874dd301843548c034a3d2973658.png" alt="" class="cat">
```

More about paths : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp